# Questions about Domains and DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain, virtualhost

I am totally new to the DNS and server hosting world and not quite sure what I need.

I want to get a domain, forward it to my own server, so that the user sees example.com in the url bar and example.com/foo/bar will work.
Depending on what subdomain it is, it should do different things (another base-directory at webserver, ftp, etc). 
Also my email should be able to be sent to and received by that server.

What irritates me, is the fact, that in the A-record I can only list IP-addresses and no ports.
So do I have to set up a nameserver on my own server? Or do I accomplish this via vhosts on my webserver?

I would appreciate any help or link to a tutorial.

I know how DNS works, know some basic apache-stuff, etc... so no need to explain that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to run your own DNS server, unless you want to play with it. most domain registrars allow direct control over your domain's dns records through their web interfaces, and so forth.

as far as hosting multiple subdomains, that's pretty easy with apache's `VirtualHost` directives. you just create a virtualhost with a ServerName of `subdomain.example.com` and set the `DocumentRoot` for that subdomain to be whereever on your file system

example of name-based virtual hosts in apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domainx/htdocs/
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAlias *.subdomain.example.com
  ...
</virtualHost>
```

Comment: excellent, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

It helps to remember the OSI model:

```
IP Address - Layer 3 - Network layer - Identifies the host
TCP Ports  - Layer 4 - Transport Layer - Identifies the process
```

At least at the present time, DNS only maps a human convenient name to a particular host, i.e.,  IP Address. The TCP Ports was supposed to be handled by Well Known Ports.

Answer (score -1):

You set an A record to point to your server, there is no need for ports. Port 80 is the default web server port, so if you type `http://yourdomain.com/` it will send the request to `yourdomain.com` on port 80.

Comment: What if he wants to send it to *ANOTHER* port?

Comment: Then like everyone else, he has to add the port to the request.